# Обособление в предложении "Он хорохорился, распрямлял грудь, поднимал голову и осматривал всё и вся как будто спрашивая"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, деепричастный-оборот

> Он хорохорился, распрямлял грудь, поднимал голову и осматривал всё и вся как будто спрашивая...

Обособлять что-то в данном предложении?

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под обособлением целого предложения? Я с таким что-то незнаком. Или Вас просто интересует, правильно ли расставлены запятые?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой , Я изменил формулировку вопроса. (Лучше поздно, чем никогда, не так, ли?:))

Comment: Действительно)) Хорошо, что исправили)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Он хорохорился, распрямлял грудь, поднимал голову и осматривал всё и вся, как будто спрашивая...**

Обособляется деепричастный оборот, к к которому относится сравнительный союз КАК БУДТО.